# What would disable a foreign key constraints?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database and all the foreign key constraints are disabled. No one went in as disabled them manually. Can SQL Server disable them automatically for any reason? Would a backup or restore turn them off?

How do I go about turning them back on?

We're using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Do you mean disabled or non trusted ? Could you publish the output of this query `SELECT fk.is_not_trusted, * FROM sys.foreign_keys fk` ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean - SYS.FOREIGN_KEYS.is_disabled is set to 1.

Comment: And `is_not_trusted` bit ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean - Some are 1 some are 0. Depends if the table was bulk loaded. But all are is_disabled 1 for some unknown reason.

Comment: Do you have also CHECK constraints disabled and/or not trusted (`SELECT * FROM sys.check_constraints`) ? *Maybe* some constraints were disabled to allow import of data that contains also invalid rows. In this case, those invalid rows should be deleted and FK & CK constraints reenabled & validated.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean - same all are disabled, all are not trusted

Comment: Could you check the import script to see if there are `alter table ... nocheck constraint ...` statements ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38201/discussion-between-justin808-and-bogdan-sahlean)

Comment: @Justin808 - I realize that you have long-ago resolved this, but it's the dialog that helps the rest of us make leaps of understanding. Please consider keeping things in the open in the future, "for the good of all." Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server do not disable constraints automatically. Even Backup and restore can not turn them off on its own.

Only way to disable constraint is by running Alter Table command like this one:

```
ALTER TABLE table_Name NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all
```

To turn on all constraint on one table:

```
ALTER TABLE table_Name CHECK CONSTRAINT all
```

To turn constrains for all table in database, you can use this command:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL" 
GO
```

Comment: Simply issuing 'CHECK' on an existing CONSTRAINT will not cause it to be instantly trusted, if there is legacy data that violates the CHECK. CHECK does turn on the 'checking' for the CONSTRAINT, but to bring back 'Trust', you need to issue 'WITH CHECK' in addition: 
`ALTER TABLE [foo] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_foo_bar];

ALTER TABLE [foo] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;`